# Self variable not updated after running function in different class

Tags: python, function, class, self

I have a class (AngleInfo) in a file (Display.py) with a self variable (WheelAngle) which is not updated after running a function (GetAngle). This function is being called in a class in a second file (ManageInfo.py) with a trigger based on events. When I try to use the WheelAngle in a second class (AngleProcess) in Display.py, the value doesn't update from the initialization. When the function is triggered in the MessageHandler class, it has access to raw data being represented by `m` in the GetAngle declaration.

There is another class (SpeedInfo) in a different file (Radar.py) where the self variable (VehicleSpeed) is being updated after running its corresponding information retrieval function (GetSpeed) in the ManageInfo class.

The working case has a threading system, but after replicating it in the non-working case I found no improvement. I don't understand why the WheelAngle is not being updated inside the class and comparing with the working case hasn't brought me closer to the answer.

So basically after I run GetAngle I see WheelAngle has the correct value inside that function but when I call the self variable in the UpdatePlot function of the AngleProcess class in the Display.py file I get the initial value. I even tried to create a different function in the AngleInfo class to access WheelAngle and then call this function in the UpdatePlot function in the AngleProcess class, but the result is the same.

Keep in mind a working example is not possible since it requires live data being sent. Also, even though WheelAngle and VehSpeed don't seem to be used, the code that follows has been ommited for simplicity!

Any ideas? There is a sample of the code below. Thank you!

Display.py

```
class AngleInfo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.WheelAngle = 0

    def GetAngle(self,m):
        self.WheelAngle = float(m) # Angle is correct

class AngleProcess():
    def __init__(self):
        self.AngleInfoObj = AngleInfo()

    def UpdatePlot(self,tupledata):
        WheelAngle = self.AngleInfoObj.WheelAngle # Angle is set to initial
```

Radar.py

```
class SpeedInfo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,page):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

        self.VehSpeed = 0

    def run(self):
        VehSpeed = self.VehSpeed # Speed is correct

    def GetSpeed(self,m):
        self.VehSpeed = float(m) # Speed is correct
```

ManageInfo.py

```
from AurixCAN import Receiver
from Radar import SpeedInfo
from Display import AngleInfo

class MessageHandler:
    def __init__(self,page):
        self.SpeedInfo = SpeedInfo(page)
        self.AngleInfo = AngleInfo()

        DataSet = Receiver(canIDsandCalls={0xE:[self.SpeedInfo.GetSpeed,self.AngleInfo.GetAngle]})
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that illustrates how you use these classes. Then explain how the output differs from what you want.

Comment: post the actual code which calls  `GetAngle()` and the code that reads the final `WheelAngle`

Comment: I see no issues in the way you've set up your classes, but it's hard to see when the calling code is not there. That probably would have been more useful than the radar.py block. I'd start by at least stepping through your code line by line. I suspect there's an issue in the way you've created your object

Comment: Note that `AngleProcess.UpdatePlot` declares a local variable `WheelAngle` that is never used. Similarly `SpeedInfo.run` declares a local variable `VehSpeed` that is never used.

Comment: By convention, python programmers start function names and variable names with lower case letters. When you start a function name with "get" this should mean that the function returns something. We usually name a function "set" when it modifies a value. So for example `GetSpeed()` should be renamed to `set_speed()`.

Comment: There still is no executable code here, only class definitions. In order to help you, we need code that we can run and see what the output is. In addition, you have introduced a new class or function named `Receiver` that is not declared. I suspect that this is unimportant to your question, so you should remove it.

Comment: "Keep in mind a working example is not possible since it requires live data being sent." A working example is always possible with a little bit of effort. Your question is about how some classes work and shouldn't depend on "live data being sent". You can create variables with example data that illustrate the problem.

Comment: I have updated the post. A MWE is complicated for this application, as I explain there. I have added the calling of GetAngle() and similar. Usage of the final variables is being omitted for ease of reading. I appreciate the comments about the convention, to be honest all the names were changed for some clarity here, future work is needed.

Comment: I don't know how to fake the triggers for the execution of GetSpeed and GetAngle in the class MessageHandler. When they are being run, they have access to this m variable which contains raw data. I'm struggling to determine what information is relevant, but you can assume I get a random integer in both and that is `m`.

Comment: Check the updated post. I'm doing my best to provide all the revelant information without going outside the scope, as it is a complex appllication.